# Adding systemversioned table and history table to entityframeworkcore context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two tables that I need to add to my entityframecore version 3.1 project. I basically have two tables called PersonNote(system versioned table) and 
 PersonNoteHistoryTable (History table). I need to add them to the entityframecore project and not sure exactly how to do it with these
 tables.

Tables

[image]

I have created a model named PersonNote and the following two DbSetProperties of the type PersonNote

```
 public DbSet<PersonNote> PersonNotes { get; set; }
 public DbSet<PersonNote> PersonNotesHistory { get; set; }
```

In the modelcreating I have tried to map to the tables this way

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<PersonNote>()
                .ToTable("PersonNotes", "PersonNote")
                .ToTable("PersonNotesHistory", "PersonNoteHistory")
                .HasKey(a => new { a.Id });
```

Could somebody tell me if it is the correct way to do it or am i missing something ?

Context class

```
public class OrganisationContext : SagitarriContext
    {
        private readonly ITimeProvider _timeProvider;
        private readonly IUserContextResolverFactory _userContextResolver;

        public OrganisationContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public OrganisationContext(DbContextOptions options, ITimeProvider timeProvider, IUserContextResolverFactory userContextResolver)
            : base(options)
        {
            _timeProvider = timeProvider;
            _userContextResolver = userContextResolver;
        }

        public DbSet<PersonNote> PersonNotes { get; set; }

        public DbSet<PersonNote> PersonNotesHistory { get; set; }

        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            GenerateColumnValues(_userContextResolver.GetResolver().Email);
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }

        public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            GenerateColumnValues(_userContextResolver.GetResolver().Email);
            return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        private void GenerateColumnValues(string userEmail)
        {
            ChangeTrackerAdded<Data.Models.User>(e =>
            {
                e.Property(p => p.Created).CurrentValue = _timeProvider.UtcNow;
                e.Property(p => p.Modified).CurrentValue = _timeProvider.UtcNow;
                e.Property(p => p.CreatedBy).CurrentValue = userEmail;
                e.Property(p => p.ModifiedBy).CurrentValue = userEmail;
            });

            ChangeTrackerModified<Data.Models.User>(e =>
            {
                e.Property(p => p.Modified).CurrentValue = _timeProvider.UtcNow;
                e.Property(p => p.ModifiedBy).CurrentValue = userEmail;
            });

            ChangeTrackerAdded<Address>(e =>
            {
                e.Property(p => p.Created).CurrentValue = _timeProvider.UtcNow;
                e.Property(p => p.Modified).CurrentValue = _timeProvider.UtcNow;
                e.Property(p => p.CreatedBy).CurrentValue = userEmail;
                e.Property(p => p.ModifiedBy).CurrentValue = userEmail;
            });

            ChangeTrackerAdded<Person>(e =>
            {
                e.Property(p => p.Created).CurrentValue = _timeProvider.UtcNow;
                e.Property(p => p.Modified).CurrentValue = _timeProvider.UtcNow;
                e.Property(p => p.CreatedBy).CurrentValue = userEmail;
                e.Property(p => p.ModifiedBy).CurrentValue = userEmail;
            });

            ChangeTrackerModified<Person>(e =>
            {
                e.Property(p => p.Modified).CurrentValue = _timeProvider.UtcNow;
                e.Property(p => p.ModifiedBy).CurrentValue = userEmail;
            });

            ChangeTrackerAdded<Client>(e =>
            {
                e.Property(p => p.Created).CurrentValue = _timeProvider.UtcNow;
                e.Property(p => p.Modified).CurrentValue = _timeProvider.UtcNow;
                e.Property(p => p.CreatedBy).CurrentValue = userEmail;
                e.Property(p => p.ModifiedBy).CurrentValue = userEmail;
            });

            ChangeTrackerAdded<Data.Models.Representative>(e =>
            {
                e.Property(p => p.Created).CurrentValue = _timeProvider.UtcNow;
                e.Property(p => p.Modified).CurrentValue = _timeProvider.UtcNow;
                e.Property(p => p.CreatedBy).CurrentValue = userEmail;
                e.Property(p => p.ModifiedBy).CurrentValue = userEmail;
            });

            ChangeTrackerAdded<Hierarchy>(e =>
            {
                e.Property(p => p.Created).CurrentValue = _timeProvider.UtcNow;
                e.Property(p => p.Modified).CurrentValue = _timeProvider.UtcNow;
                e.Property(p => p.CreatedBy).CurrentValue = userEmail;
                e.Property(p => p.ModifiedBy).CurrentValue = userEmail;
            });

            ChangeTrackerAdded<ClientRepresentative>(e =>
            {
                e.Property(p => p.Created).CurrentValue = _timeProvider.UtcNow;
                e.Property(p => p.Modified).CurrentValue = _timeProvider.UtcNow;
                e.Property(p => p.CreatedBy).CurrentValue = userEmail;
                e.Property(p => p.ModifiedBy).CurrentValue = userEmail;
            });
        }

        private void ChangeTrackerAdded<T>(Action<EntityEntry<T>> action) where T : class
        {
            ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added).ToList().ForEach(action);
        }

        private void ChangeTrackerModified<T>(Action<EntityEntry<T>> action) where T : class
        {
            ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList().ForEach(action);
        }


        public virtual Data.Models.Representative GetRecruiter(int userId)
        {
            var user = User
                .Include(x => x.Client.Representative.User.Person)
                .Include(x => x.Representative.RecruitedByRepresentative.User.Person)
                .Include(x => x.Client.Representative.RecruitedByRepresentative.RepresentativeTierHistory)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Tier)
                .Include(x => x.Representative.RecruitedByRepresentative.RepresentativeTierHistory)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Tier)
                .First(x => x.Id == userId);

            return user.Representative?.RecruitedByRepresentative ?? user.Client?.Representative;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<UnregisteredPerson>().HasNoKey();
            modelBuilder.Entity<RepresentativeViewModel>().HasNoKey();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Recruiter>().HasNoKey();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceRepresentative>().HasNoKey();
            modelBuilder.Entity<SupervisionHistoryDetail>().HasNoKey();
            modelBuilder.Entity<TierHistoryDetail>().HasNoKey();

            modelBuilder.Entity<PersonNote>()
                .ToTable("PersonNotes", "PersonNote")
                .ToTable("PersonNotesHistory", "PersonNoteHistory")
                .HasKey(a => new { a.Id });

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Update 1 based on recommendation

```
     public DbSet<PersonNote> PersonNotes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PersonNoteHistory> PersonNotesHistory { get; set; }


 modelBuilder.Entity<PersonNote>()
                .ToTable("PersonNotes", "PersonNote")
                .HasKey(a => new { a.Id });

            modelBuilder.Entity<PersonNoteHistory>()
                .ToTable("PersonNotesHistory", "PersonNoteHistory")
                .HasKey(a => new { a.Id });
```

Answer (score 0):

See the signature of `ToTable` :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypebuilderextensions.totable?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalEntityTypeBuilderExtensions_ToTable_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_EntityTypeBuilder_System_String_System_String_

```cs
/// <summary>
///     Configures the table that the entity type maps to when targeting a relational database.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="entityTypeBuilder"> The builder for the entity type being configured. </param>
/// <param name="name"> The name of the table. </param>
/// <param name="schema"> The schema of the table. </param>
/// <returns> The same builder instance so that multiple calls can be chained. </returns>
public static EntityTypeBuilder ToTable(
    [NotNull] this EntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder,
    [CanBeNull] string name,
    [CanBeNull] string schema)
```

You can't specify the DbSet property like you do :

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonNote>()
    .ToTable("PersonNotes", "PersonNote")
    .ToTable("PersonNotesHistory", "PersonNoteHistory")
    .HasKey(a => new { a.Id });
```

You can't map one entity (class) to two database tables.
You need a second entity (class) to refer the history table.

Actualy EF Core don't support table-per-concrete-type, you can't use a base class :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

You need to duplicate `PersonNote`.

Comment: I have updated the post as per your recommendation. Is that correct ?

Comment: No, the second parameter of the method `ToTable` is the schema. When the class has the same name as the table, you don't need use `ToTable`. You can remove this calls.